Google Calendar API - Error extracting work location
I'm trying to get the work location from the Google Calendar API.
In my calendar UI I see:

As you can see, on monday 1st and tuesday 2nd I work from Home, on wednesday 3rd I work from office and the thursday and friday again from home.
The API call to
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<calendar-id>/events?eventTypes=workingLocation&timeMin=2024-03-31T22:00:00.000Z&timeMax=2024-04-05T22:00:00.000Z I got
{
    "kind": "calendar#events",
    "etag": "",
    "summary": "<calendar-id>",
    "description": "",
    "updated": "2024-04-03T12:25:54.409Z",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Rome",
    "accessRole": "owner",
    "defaultReminders": [
        {
            "method": "popup",
            "minutes": 10
        }
    ],
    "nextSyncToken": "",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "\"\"",
            "id": "",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=cGljNluZy5pdA",
            "created": "2022-10-13T07:57:46.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-01-24T14:27:37.895Z",
            "summary": "Casa",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2022-10-17"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2022-10-18"
            },
            "recurrence": [
                "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20221031,20221107,20221128,20221219,20230424",
                "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO"
            ],
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "aaaaaa@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "homeOffice",
                "homeOffice": {}
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "",
            "id": "",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=A",
            "created": "2022-07-07T10:51:06.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-01-24T14:27:37.895Z",
            "summary": "Casa",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2022-07-08"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2022-07-09"
            },
            "recurrence": [
                "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20220708,20221223,20221230,20230303,20230317,20230414,20230428",
                "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR"
            ],
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "sdsdsdsds@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "homeOffice",
                "homeOffice": {}
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "\"dsdsds\"",
            "id": "dsds",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=M2NvOXFzNTlwcGwdsdsdsdsY29uc3VsdGluZy5pdA",
            "created": "2022-07-07T10:51:03.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-01-24T14:27:40.460Z",
            "summary": "Casa",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2022-07-07"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2022-07-08"
            },
            "recurrence": [
                "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20220707,20221027,20221117,20221124,20221215,20221222,20221229,20230202,20230323,20230427",
                "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH"
            ],
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "dsdsds@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "homeOffice",
                "homeOffice": {}
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "\"dsds\"",
            "id": "dsds",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=YWliY3BxN3JyNHZdsds9uc3VsdGluZy5pdA",
            "created": "2024-04-03T10:32:19.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-04-03T10:32:19.199Z",
            "summary": "Casa",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2024-04-04"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2024-04-05"
            },
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "dddddd.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "homeOffice",
                "homeOffice": {}
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "",
            "id": "dddd",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=amwwdddd
            "created": "2024-04-03T10:32:19.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-04-03T10:32:19.199Z",
            "summary": "Casa",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2024-04-05"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2024-04-06"
            },
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "dddd@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "homeOffice",
                "homeOffice": {}
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "\"dddd\"",
            "id": "dddd",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dddd",
            "created": "2024-04-03T10:32:19.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-04-03T10:32:19.199Z",
            "summary": "Casa",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2024-04-02"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2024-04-03"
            },
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "dddd@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "homeOffice",
                "homeOffice": {}
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "dddd",
            "id": "dddd",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dddd",
            "created": "2022-10-13T07:57:48.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-04-03T12:25:52.311Z",
            "summary": "Company Building (Ufficio)",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2022-10-18"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2022-10-19"
            },
            "recurrence": [
                "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20221025,20221101,20221108,20221115,20221122,20221129,20221213,20221220,20221227,20230117,20230131,20230228,20230307,20230314,20230321,20230425",
                "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20240408;BYDAY=TU"
            ],
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "dddd@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "officeLocation",
                "officeLocation": {
                    "buildingId": "HQ",
                    "label": "Company Building"
                }
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        },
        {
            "kind": "calendar#event",
            "etag": "\"dddd\"",
            "id": "dddd",
            "status": "confirmed",
            "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=ddddA",
            "created": "2024-04-03T12:25:54.000Z",
            "updated": "2024-04-03T12:25:54.409Z",
            "summary": "Company Building (Ufficio)",
            "creator": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "organizer": {
                "email": "myemail",
                "self": true
            },
            "start": {
                "date": "2024-04-03"
            },
            "end": {
                "date": "2024-04-04"
            },
            "recurrence": [
                "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE"
            ],
            "transparency": "transparent",
            "visibility": "public",
            "iCalUID": "vvvvvv@google.com",
            "sequence": 0,
            "reminders": {
                "useDefault": false
            },
            "workingLocationProperties": {
                "type": "officeLocation",
                "officeLocation": {
                    "buildingId": "HQ",
                    "label": "Company Building"
                }
            },
            "eventType": "workingLocation"
        }
    ]
}

It seems to be a little bit confused... I was expecting only workingLocation events from 2024-03-31T22:00:00.000Z (2024-04-01 00:00 in my fuse (GMT+2)) to 2024-04-05T22:00:00.000Z (2024-04-06 00:00 in my fuse (GMT+2)) but I got also event starts at 2022-10-17 (???).
How can I get only working location events of this week?
